# remove one image from imageCollection in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-7

I work with google earth engine on an imageCollection from landsat7. Some of those images are 'corrupted'. So I would like to remove one image from an image collection.

Actually I have :

```js
var collectionLS7NDVI0 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,6,'month'))
    .map(addTime);

var listOfImages = collectionLS7NDVI0.toList(collectionLS7NDVI0.size());
print(listOfImages)
0: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/19990610 (2 bands)
1: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20000609 (2 bands)
2: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20010610 (2 bands)
3: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20020610 (2 bands)
4: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20030610 (2 bands)
5: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20040609 (2 bands)
6: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20050610 (2 bands)
7: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20060610 (2 bands)
8: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20070610 (2 bands)
9: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20080609 (2 bands)
10: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20090610 (2 bands)
11: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20100610 (2 bands)
12: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20110610 (2 bands)
13: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20120609 (2 bands)
14: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20130610 (2 bands)
15: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20140610 (2 bands)
16: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20150610 (2 bands)
17: 
Image LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20160609 (2 bands)
```

And I want to remove images `6` (2005).

Any ideas are welcome

Etienne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove images of a collection by constructing a filter that selects the images you want to remove, then negate the filter using [ee.Filter.not()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefilternot).

```js
var MAX_LIST_SIZE = 100;

var collectionLS7NDVI0 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,6,'month'));
print('listOfImages', collectionLS7NDVI0.toList(MAX_LIST_SIZE));

// Filter out image(s) from 2005.
var filtered = collectionLS7NDVI0.filter(
  ee.Filter.date('2005', '2006').not()
);
print('filtered', filtered.toList(MAX_LIST_SIZE));
```