# How to filter image collection by date, excluding a date from a date range in Google Earth Engine

Tags: filter, google-earth-engine

I am using air surface temp data from 2015 in Google Earth Engine but there is missing data for June 19, 2015 which is assigned the value 9.9621e+36.

So I need to create a date range from Jan 1 2015 to Dec 31 2015 which excludes June 19 2015. I know how to filter by date:

```js
var AST2015 = ee.ImageCollection('NCEP_RE/surface_temp')
                .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31');
```

But as long as that one June date is in their my mean and other stats are ruined. SOS

Answer (score 11):

You can remove images from an image collection by creating a date filter for the 'bad/missing' data and then remove it using [ee.Filter.not()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefilternot). For example:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NCEP_RE/surface_temp');
var AST2015 = collection.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01');

var start_bad_data = '2015-06-18T00:00:00';
var end_bad_data = '2015-06-20T00:00:00';
var bad_data_filter = ee.Filter.date(start_bad_data, end_bad_data);

// Select the bad data.
var AST2015_bad_data = AST2015.filter(bad_data_filter);
// Select the good data.
var AST2015_good_data = AST2015.filter(bad_data_filter.not());

Map.addLayer(AST2015, {}, 'AST2015');
Map.addLayer(AST2015_bad_data, {}, 'AST2015_bad_data');
Map.addLayer(AST2015_good_data, {}, 'AST2015_good_data');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove images of a collection by constructing a filter that selects the images you want to remove, then negate the filter using `ee.Filter.not()`. Example is shown below from another [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263694/remove-one-image-from-imagecollection-in-google-earth-engine?rq=1)

```
var MAX_LIST_SIZE = 100;

var collectionLS7NDVI0 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,6,'month'));
print('listOfImages', collectionLS7NDVI0.toList(MAX_LIST_SIZE));

// Filter out image(s) from 2005.
var filtered = collectionLS7NDVI0.filter(
  ee.Filter.date('2005', '2006').not()
);
print('filtered', filtered.toList(MAX_LIST_SIZE));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a filter to filter the images by month using the following command:

```
ee.Filter.calendarRange (6,10, 'month')
```

Answer (score 0):

For people wanting to know how to use the `filter.not` functionality with the python API (like I was), use this:

```py
start_date = '2018-06-16'
end_date = '2019-02-25'
dont_start_date = '2018-06-18'
dont_end_date = '2019-02-23'

im_coll = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT')
           .filterBounds(aoi)
           .filterDate(ee.Date(start_date),ee.Date(end_date))
           .map(lambda img: img.set('date', ee.Date(img.date()).format('YYYYMMdd')))
           .sort('date'))

bad_filter = ee.Filter.Not(ee.Filter.date(dont_start_date, dont_end_date))
im_coll = im_coll.filter(bad_filter)
```