# Seasonal analysis in Google Earth Engine

Tags: modis, ndvi, google-earth-engine, seasonal-analysis

I want to perform a seasonal analysis of the `MODIS NDVI` dataset in GEE. I want to analyse for every year the months from May to September and thus, I need to remove the rest of the months from the dataset for every year. 
I have no idea how to do this. I have found this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263694/remove-one-image-from-imagecollection-in-google-earth-engine/263727) but this is just for one image for a year.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calendarRange`  to filter the whole collection and only keep images from May to September (inclusive).

```js
var ModisMaySept = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13A1')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(5,8,'month'))

print(ModisMaySept)
```